# Why don't the HTML helpers output anything in this ASP MVC view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my asp mvc view.  Note that it has a div which contains a simple form.  I am using Html.TextBox() to try to output input elements but nothing is output.  The form renders properly but where I expect to see the input tag there is nothing.

I'm sure this is a total beginner mistake but what am I doing wrong?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="gnodotnet.Web.Controllers" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="sponsorsContainer" class="container" style="width: 110px; float: left; height:482px; margin-right: 20px;"> &nbsp; </div>
    <div id="calendarContainer" class="container" style="width: 500px; height: 482px; float: left;"> &nbsp;
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=462&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFAD57&amp;src=ck1tburd835alnt9rr3li68128%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23AB8B00&amp;ctz=America%2FChicago" style=" border-width:0 " width="482" height="462" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>    
    <div id="mailingListContainer" class="container" style="width: 95px; float: left; height:182px; margin-left: 20px;"> 
        <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
            <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
           <h4>Subscribe to our Mailing List</h4>
           Name: <% Html.TextBox("subscribeName"); %>
           Email: <% Html.TextBox("subscribeEmail"); %>
           <% Html.Button("subcribeOk", "Subscribe", HtmlButtonType.Submit); %>
       <% } %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: the inline style makes me weep.

Comment: comment like that makes me weep. At least be kind enough to provide insight into alternatives.

Comment: I DO intend to move to the Sparc engine but this is already my first sharp architecture, asp mvc, and nhibernate project - don't want to throw in too many new frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
<%=Html.TextBox
```

instead of

```
<% Html.TextBox
```

<%= is equivalent to Response.Write, whereas <% merely opens a code block.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to check the return types of the `HtmlHelper` methods. Some, such as `RenderPartial`, return `void`. These internally used `Response.Write()` or another method to output some HTML directly to the response steream.

Thus, they can be used in an ASP code block, which executes any inline code, like so:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SubsciberProfile") %>
```

However, most of the built-in form methods, such as `Html.TextBox`, return a `string`. In these cases, you must execute the code *and* send it to the response. If you used

```
<% Html.TextBox("subscriberEmail") %>
```

then the TextBox HTML would be returned as a `string` and promptly discarded. It is the equivalent of doing something like this:

```
string name = "John Doe";
name.Replace("Doe","Smith");
```

Note that the value returned by `Replace` is never assigned to anything, so the evaluation of the method is performed but its return value never used.

Instead, we must use something like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("subscriberEmail") %>
```

Note the equals sign! This means the code block should evaluate *and output* the result of the method. As pointed out above, `<%= someString %>` is shorthand for `<% Response.Write(someString) %>`. This is subtle, but very important to remember.